# Why does grub selection no longer appear on my dual-boot system?

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, fedora

I had installed a Ubuntu 12.04 and Fedora 17 dual boot on my system. During the installation I had installed Ubuntu first and Fedora later. Fedora had recognized Ubuntu and added it to the GRUB OS selection list. Afterwards I installed some routine updates on my Ubuntu and after that I am just not able to see the GRUB OS selection anymore when I boot. I am unable to understand what happened, both Fedora and Ubuntu use GRUB 2.0. Also it seems Ubuntu is not able to recognize other existing linux operating systems; because in the beginning I had installed Fedora first and Ubuntu later, but Ubuntu did not recognize Fedora at all, while Fedora recognized Ubuntu when I installed the other way round.

Comment: Update: Ubuntu 12.04 uses GRUB 1.99 while Fedora uses GRUB 2.0. Maybe that is a reason

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the Grub Customizer with

```
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

When you open the app, it shows all the detected OS's (as well as old kernel versions). You can tick/untick the boxes to show/hide options at bootup.

It may be possible that Fedora is hidden. If so, you can easily fix it with the customizer.